# JHipster "URL must start with 'jdbc'" error on Heroku

Tags: heroku, spring-boot, jhipster

My application was running fine locally but when I deployed to heroku, I got application error. I tried several times the same thing happening. I checked database connection and everything is fine. These are my logs

```
2017-06-13T09:20:30.840039+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.840041+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.840040+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.840042+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.840040+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.840042+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937134+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.Dele
gatingMetricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMetricsConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyExcep
tion: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setHikariDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
ry.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean insta
ntiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSour
ce' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2017-06-13T09:20:30.840043+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937128+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-06-13 09:20:30.935 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937130+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937136+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.java:667)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937139+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937137+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937138+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcesso
r.java:366)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937140+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937139+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937143+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937141+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937141+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937142+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937143+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937146+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937144+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:1173)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937147+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937145+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937146+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937150+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:235)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937148+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937148+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937149+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937150+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937151+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937158+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937156+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937159+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937157+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937160+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mycompany.myapp.Blog3App.main(Blog3App.java:66)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937161+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937160+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937161+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937162+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937165+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937163+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937166+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied depend
ency expressed through method 'setHikariDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined i
n class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.be
ans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U
RL must start with 'jdbc'
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937163+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937164+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937169+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937167+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.java:667)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937167+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937168+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcesso
r.java:366)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937169+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937170+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937171+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937172+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937171+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937173+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937175+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1180)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937173+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937174+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937175+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937176+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937177+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937193+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/sp
ringframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationExceptio
n: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937178+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.java:659)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937178+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 34 common frames omitted
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937195+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937196+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:1173)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937198+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937196+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937197+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937201+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937199+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937202+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937199+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937205+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSour
ce' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937202+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937203+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.java:659)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937204+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 50 common frames omitted
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937206+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937209+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937207+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937209+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(DatabaseDriver.java:268)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937207+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 62 common frames omitted
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937208+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937212+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:80)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937210+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:238)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937211+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:183)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937211+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937215+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937213+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937216+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 63 common frames omitted
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937213+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937214+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937215+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-06-13T09:20:30.937217+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-06-13T09:20:31.436235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-06-13T09:20:31.460943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-13T09:24:12.753908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=serene-citadel-75498.herokuapp.com request_id=66b02e97-98a8-442c-85f1-d889ad25ec01
fwd="84.54.96.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-13T09:24:13.555911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-citadel-75498.herokuapp.com request_id=4a28374e-0005-4ed5-bc26-1b
0a799f76bb fwd="84.54.96.137" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**EDIT** : applicaiton-prod.yml:

```
datasource: 
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&characterEnco‌​ding=utf8&useSSL=fal‌​se 
    username: root 
    password: password
```

applicaiton-heroku.yml:

```
datasource: 
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: The key is here: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'` Could you post the whole JDBC connection string?

Comment: datasource:
**type:** com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        **url:** jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
        **username:** root
        **password:** password

Comment: Have you checked which profile is activated in your logs?

Comment: I'm with @GaëlMarziou on this. Is it possible that you profile is not set correctly and that's why the app uses not your specific properties, but defaults back to application.properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Heroku account has not been verified, then you cannot install AddOns (such as the Database AddOn).  You can solve this by adding a credit card in Heroku's dashboard.  Full instructions can be found in [Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification):

> To verify your Heroku account:
>
> 1) Go to your account page.
>
> 2) Click the Billing tab.
>
> 3) Click Add Credit Card.

This error is now printed during deployment in JHipster v4.5.3+, in previous versions it was ignored silently.