# deployment of jhipster app using git type deployment givess error

Tags: spring, maven, heroku, jhipster

I am deploying my jhipster generated application in heroku using Git type deployment option but I am getting the below error
It is a Maven and My Sql based application. Can any one help why the deployment failing?

When I check at heroku generated url, it says Application Error

Please find the detail error log:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.248]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\kishore>cd C:\mnkb\projects\agri

...

C:\mnkb\projects\agri>jhipster heroku
Using JHipster version installed globally
Executing jhipster:heroku
Options:
Heroku configuration is starting
? Name to deploy as:  AgriAppR1
? On which region do you want to deploy ? us

Using existing Git repository

Heroku CLI deployment plugin already installed

Creating Heroku application and setting up node environment
https://agri-app-r-1.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/agri-app-r-1.git

Provisioning addons
No new addons created

Creating Heroku deployment files
identical src\main\resources\config\bootstrap-heroku.yml
 conflict src\main\resources\config\application-heroku.yml
? Overwrite src\main\resources\config\application-heroku.yml? overwrite
    force src\main\resources\config\application-heroku.yml
identical Procfile
identical pom.xml

Skipping build

Updating Git repository
git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .yo-rc.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Procfile.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in pom.xml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/main/resources/config/application-heroku.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/main/resources/config/bootstrap-heroku.yml.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
git commit -m "Deploy to Heroku" --allow-empty

Configuring Heroku

Deploying application
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Executing: ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
remote:        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Building Agri 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote:        [INFO] Copying 5 resources
remote:        [INFO] Copying 22 resources
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote:        [INFO] Copying 5 resources
remote:        [INFO] Copying 22 resources
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (docker-resources) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote:        [INFO] Copying 2 resources
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/target/test-results/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 112 source files to /tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/target/classes
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote:        [INFO] Copying 4 resources
remote:        [INFO] Copying 2 resources
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 29 source files to /tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/target/test-classes
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Tests are skipped.
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (without-cucumber) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Tests are skipped.
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:report (post-unit-test) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Packaging webapp
remote:        [INFO] Assembling webapp [agri] in [/tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/target/agri-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
remote:        [INFO] Processing war project
remote:        [INFO] Copying webapp webResources [/tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/src/main/webapp] to [/tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/target/agri-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
remote:        [INFO] Webapp assembled in [358 msecs]
remote:        [INFO] Building war: /tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/target/agri-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO]
remote:        [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ agri ---
remote:        [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/target/agri-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/kb/agri/agri/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/agri-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
remote:        [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_3b7b8144c9b943ba0447cd31d27f16de/pom.xml to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/kb/agri/agri/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/agri-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time: 17.913 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-17T15:39:42Z
remote:        [INFO] Final Memory: 75M/417M
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 231.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v5
remote:        https://agri-r-1.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/agri-r-1.git
   65c512a..5f46252  HEAD -> master

Your app should now be live. To view it run
        heroku open
And you can view the logs with this command
        heroku logs --tail
After application modification, redeploy it with
        jhipster heroku
Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!

C:\mnkb\projects\agri>heroku open

C:\mnkb\projects\agri>heroku logs  --tail
2018-02-17T15:40:40.755133+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-17T15:40:40.755146+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-17T15:40:40.755135+00:00 app[web.1]: :: JHipster ??  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE ::
2018-02-17T15:40:40.755137+00:00 app[web.1]: :: http://www.jhipster.tech ::
2018-02-17T15:40:41.078074+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-17 15:40:41.056  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.kb.agri.AgriApp                      : Starting AgriApp on 4067ef49-8ff3-46cd-93d8-126d1351ef28 with PID 4 (/app/target/agri-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war started by u47832 in /app)
2018-02-17T15:40:41.089208+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-17 15:40:41.078  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.kb.agri.AgriApp                      : The following profiles are active: prod,heroku
2018-02-17T15:40:47.196307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-17T15:40:47.211335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-17T15:40:46.998924+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-17 15:40:46.998  WARN 4 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.DelegatingMetricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMetricsConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setHikariDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052529+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-02-17 15:40:47.051 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052534+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052536+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.DelegatingMetricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMetricsConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setHikariDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052538+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052541+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052543+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052545+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052547+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052550+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052548+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052552+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052553+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052555+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052556+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052558+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052560+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052562+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052563+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052565+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052567+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052569+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052571+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052572+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:237)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052574+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052576+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052585+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052587+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052589+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052591+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052593+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.kb.agri.AgriApp.main(AgriApp.java:66)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052595+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052597+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052598+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052600+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052602+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052603+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052605+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052607+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)2018-02-17T15:40:47.052611+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052609+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setHikariDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052613+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052615+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052616+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052618+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052620+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052621+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052623+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052624+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052626+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052628+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052629+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052631+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052633+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1180)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052634+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052636+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052637+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052640+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 34 common frames omitted
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052646+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052648+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052650+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052651+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052699+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052906+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052909+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052912+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052914+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052916+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052918+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052920+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052921+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052923+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052925+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 50 common frames omitted
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052928+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052930+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052931+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052933+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 62 common frames omitted
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052936+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052937+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052940+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(DatabaseDriver.java:268)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052941+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:239)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052943+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:184)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052945+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052947+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:80)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052949+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052951+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052953+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052955+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052977+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052979+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 63 common frames omitted
2018-02-17T15:40:47.052981+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-17T15:40:48.851467+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agri-r-1.herokuapp.com request_id=80d747e7-e777-41ad-9603-7328cb34743e fwd="183.83.81.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-17T15:40:49.725662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=agri-r-1.herokuapp.com request_id=e8b1b5dd-c2b2-4c2a-8ba1-7b890b925bf7 fwd="183.83.81.98" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Can you please supply the full error log instead of a screenshot?  There should be a message in the stacktrace explaining what went wrong

Comment: Jon, I  have updated the question with full error log

Comment: Well it seems you haven't provisioned a mysql addon. What does print `heroku addons` ? It reminds me the credit card issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5510

Comment: you are right Gael, I have added  JawsDB MySQL to my app and entered credit card details now the app is deployed nicely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jhipster Application error when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518035/jhipster-application-error-when-deployed)